# The site is experiencing technical difficulties

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

When I paste code in the  function.php, my website stop working and an error shows up "The site is experiencing technical difficulties"

```
/**
 * Adding Shortcode 'box'
 */
    function boxShow($atts, $content = null ){
    //default values
    $option = shortcode_atts( array(
     'type' => '',
    ), $atts );

     ob_start(); 
    $class = $option[ 'type' ] ? str_replace( '"', '', $option[ 'type' ] ) : 'normal';
//HTML goes here
?>
<div class="box <?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content; ?></div>

<?php
$output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'box', 'boxShow' );
```

and CSS Code

```
.shadow , .success , .info{
padding: 12px 12px;
background-color: #fafafa;
border: 1px solid black;
margin-bottom:8px;
```

Comment: Did you check the [error log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) yet? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Please clarify which code you are pasting and which code already exist in your functions.php file.